# How to Filter Shell scripts using maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to filter my shell scripts using maven assembly plugin. Other properties and xml files are getting filtered correctly. However, I'm getting following message in the log for shell scripts.

Relevant assembly descriptor.

```
        <file>
        <source>src/main/config/default/buildcron.csh</source>
        <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
    </file>
```

and here is the message for not filtering above scripts in the log.
`file buildcron.csh has a filtered file extension`. Is there any way to change this default behavior?

PS: I see similar behavior with txt files.

Edit: Here is the plugin being used from POM.xml

```
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

            <executions>

                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>

                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>env/${env}.properties</filter>
                </filters>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/myapp-server.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>


</build>
```

Thanks,
Prabhjot

Comment: Can you give a little bit more output? POM Snippet? Which Assembly plugin version are you using? Can you give the complete descriptor ?

Comment: Have added the relevant section of POM.

Comment: You missed the maven assembly plugin version? Why did you configure your assembly in the install phase? Have you tried to configure your filtering in the descriptor by using a fileSet instead of a single file?

Comment: Which version I should use? won't it use latest version if I don't specify one. I believe fileset doesn't allow filtering. I used this as reference. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html

Comment: Ok, as per log version '2.2-beta-2' is being used for assembly plugin.

Comment: Also, in the shell script a variable is referred as $varname and I'm expecting ${property} to be replaced with some value from dev/qa/prod.properties file under env folder of my project. I hope assembly plugin doesn't stop filtering, if it finds anything like  $varname in the file.

Comment: Update to 2.2.1 for the assembly plugin.

Comment: and do I need to make any other changes?

Comment: I started getting following exception after updating version `[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] : org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.model.Assembly@f942c4
Assembly is incorrectly configured: null

Assembly: null is not configured correctly: Assembly ID must be present and non-empty.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define an id inside your descriptor.

```
<assembly>
   <id>conf</id>
...
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are hitting a problem discussed in [this thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Filter-executed-but-values-not-substituted-td3425193.html).  Maybe some property is clashing with the pom.

Comment: Sorry, I can't access that page. Could you please paste key-pointers here?

Answer (score 0):

I've one more concern here. Currently, I'm filtering files (logic is in assembly descriptor) in the assembly plugin. However, those properties file go only to zip folder (contains config files, shell scripts, dependent jars). The separate application jar which is being generated, doesn't have config files by default. I've to again write seperate logic ( in POM xml) for generating config files for the specific environment.

Is there any way to avoid writing duplicate logic?